# How to use php to find out (payment status and paid date) in PayPal-chained payment?

Tags: php, paypal, chained-payments

How to use php to find out (payment status and paid date) in PayPal-chained payment?

I have access to the pay key which is generated by the paypal, how can I use it in this situation? I need to know is payment completed, if so on what date?

Answer (score 0):

The [PaymentDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/) should give you what you're after.